# Fixing Craft\HttpException Error

Tags: error-message

Recently moved site to a new server.

Attempting to edit a post created before migration fails. The edit page reloads with the changes removed. Note: 1) this happens for only SOME, but not ALL of entries in the same channel. 2) the entries that fail and those that succeed are set to use the same templates.

Utilities - Logs shows this error message:

Level     error

Category  exception.Craft\HttpException.404

Message   Craft\HttpException in 
  /home/method/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:72

Comment: So you're getting a 404 when saving an entry, but it only happens on _some_ entries in a particular section?

Comment: Well, I don't ever see a 404...the entry page just refreshes. The log is what shows the 404.  And yes, only some entries have this problem. Other ones act normally. I have only seen it in one section, but I haven't tested entry after entry in each one to try to find additional problems.

Comment: Note that the published entry can be viewed on the web. Craft is blocking me from editing it.

Comment: Do you have anything like Suhosin or mod_security installed on that box by chance?

Comment: That's it. mod_security is on by default and a rule is getting triggered. Turned it off and now the entry can be modified and saved.  Thank you Brad!

Comment: mod_security strikes again!  Can you add that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 2):

That's it. mod_security is on by default and a rule is getting triggered. Turned it off and now the entry can be modified and saved. Thank you Brad!